# MYSQL count function merging

Tags: mysql

In my database table I have two columns that hold either 0 or 1.

I have `type` and `Gender`, where type means `0 => teacher` and `1 => student` and for gender: `0 => male` and `1 => female`.

How can I write a single sql query to get number of teachers, students, males and females?

Right now I have:

```
select COUNT(type) as teachers from my_table where type = 0; // Teachers
select COUNT(type) as students from my_table where type = 1; // Students
select COUNT(gender) as males from my_table where type = 0; // Males
select COUNT(gender) as females from my_table where type = 1; // Females
```

Can it be done in one query? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can do it in a single query. If you have only two types of data in your table then you don't need to specify `IN` conditions in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(type = 1, 1, 0)) as students,
       SUM(IF(type = 0, 1, 0)) as teachers,
       SUM(IF(gender = 1, 1, 0)) as females,
       SUM(IF(gender = 0, 1, 0)) as males
FROM my_table
WHERE type IN(0,1)
      AND gender IN(0,1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` for that using `SUM` function:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE type WHEN  1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS students,
       SUM(CASE type WHEN  0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS teachers,
       SUM(CASE gender WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS females,
       SUM(CASE gender WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS males
FROM my_table;
```

You can also use `COUNT` function instead of `SUM` like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE type WHEN  1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS students,
       COUNT(CASE type WHEN  0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS teachers,
       COUNT(CASE gender WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS females,
       COUNT(CASE gender WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS males
FROM my_table;
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de987/6)

Comment: thank you v much, that works too, but @omesh posted it first so accepted his answer

Answer (score 1):

You could achive this using subqueries.

```
SELECT COUNT(type) AS students,
    (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM my_table WHERE type = 0) As teachers,
    (SELECT COUNT(gender) FROM my_table WHERE gender = 1) AS females,
    (SELECT COUNT(gender) FROM my_table WHERE gender = 0) AS males
FROM my_table WHERE type = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Did you try taking each of your SQL statements and putting them together?
`SQL1 as fld1, SQL2 as fld2, someOtherFieldsIfNeeded FROM ...`